# Streaming mp3 file from external server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, audio-streaming

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application. I need to stream a .mp3 sound file from a remote server in my application.

I have tried to use `MediaElement`:

```
private MediaElement media;
// Constructor of class
            media = new MediaElement();
            media.Source = new Uri(string.Format("{0}b10en_US.mp3", mp3HostName), UriKind.Absolute);
            media.MediaFailed += media_MediaFailed;
            media.MediaEnded += media_MediaEnded;
            media.MediaOpened += media_MediaOpened;
            media.Loaded += media_Loaded;
            media.BufferingProgressChanged += media_BufferingProgressChanged;

// In a method I call the following
media.play();
```

However no sound gets played whatsoever. I added breakpoints to the mediaelement's events, but none gets fired.

I have double checked, the URI to the mp3 file is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play mp3 after media opened event is raised. I think your method(in which you are calling play is called before media opened event is raised.

you can implement some hack in mediaOpened event and your method(play). like

```
private bool isMediaLoaded = false;
private bool isPlayCalled = false;
private void PlayMP3()
{
    if(isMediaLoaded)
       media.Play();
    else
       isPlayCalled = true;
}
void MediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isMediaLoaded = true;
    if(isPlayCalled)
        MediaElement1.Play();

}
```

Comment: for some reason the MediaOpened event never fires.

Comment: did your emulator/device have access to internet? can you check that your emulator can browse the page

Comment: yes. I have tried it on a device with wifi and 3G, and on an emulator too, same results. I tried your last edit too, mediaopened still doesnt fire.

Comment: Ah, I am sure your media is not added in xaml tree! you need to add media elemen tin xaml tree like in some Grid, canvas stack panel etc to work 

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
        string url = "http://traffic.libsyn.com/slashfilmcast/Davidmichod.mp3";//your url link
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            Song track = Song.FromUri("Sample Song", new Uri(url));
            MediaPlayer.Play(track);

        }
```

`using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;` //for getting MediaPlayer

Comment: This worked, however after playing the sound I get an exception saying that the mp3 is DRM protected. Is there a workaround? (the mp3s are voice recordings, so there shouldnt be DRM on it)